# Component not rendering value

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I have the following component.

My problem is that I cannot understand why `link.title` is not shown anywhere, neither as a value in the input field nor on the `h1`.

link-item.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>{{link.title}}</h1>
    <div v-if="isViewMode()">
      <button href="" @click="toggleMode()"></button>
    </div>

    <div>
      <input v-bind:value="link.title" />
    </div>
    
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
export default defineComponent({
  name: "link-item",

  data() {
    return {
      link: {
        title: "",
        url: ""
      }
    };
  },
  ...
})
</script>
```

Page.vue

```
      <link-item 
        v-for="link in links"
        :key="link.id"
        :link="link">
      </link-item>
```

Output:

```html
<div link="[object Object]">
<h1></h1>
<!--v-if-->
<div><input></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should be defining `link` as a prop not data.

Comment: @Terry when defining like this ` props: ["link"],` I get an error `error    Unexpected mutation of "link" prop`

Comment: Because you're not supposed to mutate props. If you want to mutate props, you need to mutate at the source, to ensure data flows a single way: use emitted events or `v-model` on custom components. From your code it is not clear that you're actually mutating the prop: create a [mcve] to illustrate your use case.